# How to get difference between xdocument1 and xdocument2

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to get difference between xdocument1 and xdocument2.
on xdocument1:

```
<prices>
   <price>
     <productid>P001</productid>
     <price>1000</price>
     <effectivedate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</effectivedate>
   </price>
</prices>
```

and on xdocument2:

```
<prices>
   <price>
     <productid>P001</productid>
     <price>870</price>
     <effectivedate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</effectivedate>
   </price>
</prices>
```

How can I get the difference between them, if effectivedate and productid have same value, then it should return no price record, like this:

```
<prices/>
```

If the effectivedate is different, like these:

on xdocument1:

```
<prices>
   <price>
     <productid>P001</productid>
     <price>1000</price>
     <effectivedate>2015-05-12T00:00:00+7</effectivedate>
   </price>
</prices>
```

and on xdocument2:

```
<prices>
   <price>
     <productid>P001</productid>
     <price>870</price>
     <effectivedate>2015-05-11T00:00:00+7</effectivedate>
   </price>
</prices>
```

Then price tag should get from xdocument1, return:

```
<prices>
   <price>
     <productid>P001</productid>
     <price>1000</price>
     <effectivedate>2015-05-12T00:00:00+7</effectivedate>
   </price>
</prices>
```

Comment: It looks like you try to merge insted of diff the two documents? Then you have two single tasks: Diff both documents, if they differ, merge them.

Comment: I'd read them both into objects, then get the data you want, then build the xml back out.  If this is actually your schema, it's pretty simple, shouldn't be hard

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee: this what i've tried so far: doc1.Descendants("Price").Cast<XNode>().Except(doc2.Descendants("Price").Cast<XNode>(), new XNodeEqualityComparer()); but it always return doc1 even when productid and effectivedate are same

Comment: @Jonesy : Hi, can you share more your thoughts/algorithm? i didn't get it, thanks before

Comment: @alwe: could we use XNodeEqualityComparer() ? how to achieve it? i already try, but it compare all node when diff the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work as you want it to.

```
var query =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement(
            "prices",
            from p1 in xdocument1.Root.Elements("price")
            join p2 in xdocument2.Root.Elements("price")
                on p1.Element("productid").Value equals p2.Element("productid").Value
            where p1.Element("effectivedate").Value != p2.Element("effectivedate").Value
            select p1));
```

It seems rather simple so please let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: yes thanks, thats work, is there any alternative like using moreLinq like exceptby on 'productid' and 'effectivedate' element? i still curious when using XNodeEqualityComparer

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following steps

1. Using hashmap with *ProductID* as the key and object containing the *effectivedate* and *price*.
2. The object can have an overridden equals methods for efficient comparison.
3. Load the either of document in the hashmap first and check with second document for similarity or difference, returning results accordingly.
4. This takes linear time O(n+m)  where n is the size/number of element of first doc and m is size/number of element of second doc to find all the differences.

I am more of a java person. I can provide a code snippet in Java in sometime.

Comment: i prefer look from linq-to-xml queries approach, it's too complicated to me :(